# XML Assert for child attribute based upon parent attribute

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, assert

I have a situation with the following XML (example snippit):

```
<foo type="color">
  <bar choice="red"/>
  <bar choice="blue"/>
</foo>
<foo type="shape">
  <bar choice="circle"/>
  <bar choice="square"/>
</foo>
```

Essentially, I want to limit the possible values for the attribute "choice" based upon the value of the parent attribute "type".  I know that an assert won't let me look at a parent value, but I thought that it should allow me to look at children values.  This would mean that I need to put the  at the parent level, but I'm not sure how this would be written to reference the child attributes.  If they were in the same element, it would be something like this:

```
<assert test="(@type='color' and @choice=('red','blue')) or (@type='shape' and @choice=('circle','square'))"/>
```

Or am I completely off base?

Answer (score 0):

to reference the attributes of child element use: `child_name/@attributeName`:
in your case, try this:

```
<assert test="(@type='color' and bar/@choice=('red','blue')) or (@type='shape' and bar/@choice=('circle','square'))"/>.
```

**Note:** the use of this assertion has some problems: for example, this XML file will be valid:

```
<foo type="color">
  <bar choice="red"/>
  <bar choice="aaaa"/>
</foo>
<foo type="shape">
  <bar choice="bbbb"/>
  <bar choice="square"/>
</foo>
```

I suggest you use `xs:alternative`